# Running python CGI script on browser generating script code not expected output

Tags: python, apache, cgi

I am trying to run a small CGI script but it is showing script code on browser not the HTML.
I am running Apache server and it's configured as per the requirement.

```
DocumentRoot "/home/user/htdocs"
<Directory "/home/user/htdocs">

   Options Indexes FollowSymLinks
   Options +ExecCGI
   AddHandler cgi-script .cgi .py
   Order allow,deny
   Allow from all
   AllowOverride None
   Require all granted
</Directory>

ScriptAlias /cgi-bin/ /home/user/cgi-bin/
```

I have put the script in cgi-bin directory and given it executable permission( chmod 755)  but it still not working.

What is it which i am missing ?

Answer (score 0):

The problem is that you have not told Apache that your are allowed to run CGI scripts in your CGI folder. Basically what your settings for the `/home/user/cgi-bin` folder, Debian have this as default in their installation (I changed the path though):

```
<Directory "/home/user/cgi-bin">
  AllowOverride None
  Options +ExecCGI -MultiViews +SymLinksIfOwnerMatch
  Order allow,deny
  Allow from all
</Directory>
```

Comment: Still getting the same issue. I changed the Directory tag as you suggested but nothing changed in the result.

Comment: @Jitu I wonder if having two `Options` arguments could mess things up. Try setting them all in one `Options` tag instead.

Comment: @Jitu Also, I assume you have `mod_python` enabled?